# Application thinks it's running with requireAdministrator

Tags: .net, uac

I have an application which has a manifest that tells it to run "asInvoker".  When I install it on my machine or any one of several other VMs I have available, the program runs normally.

Because somebody will probably ask, the app is signed.

But one clients installs the same program and the desktop icon gets the UAC shield on it and when they double-click the icon it prompts the for administrator access as if the program manifest had it set to "requireAdministrator".

We checked and both his system and mine have UAC set to the same level (Default), including the Local Security Policy settings.  None of the systems I have tried give the icon the UAC shield or require admin confirmation before launching.

I've had them uninstall and make sure the install folder got deleted (I suspected a manifest file hanging around) and that didn't help.  We checked the shortcut and the executable Properties and neither one have the "Run as administrator" checkbox set.

There's a Local Security Policy for "Detect application installations and prompt for elevation".  We tried disabling that, uninstalled and reinstalled the application and no change.

The client is running Windows 7.  I tried on Windows 7, 2008 R2 and 2012 R2. We also had the product manager try it on his Windows 7 and 2008 R2 machines.  It works on all of our systems without prompting for admin rights but it prompts for admin rights for the client.

We cannot figure out why the program is requiring admin rights for him and not for anybody else.  It shouldn't be. Is there anything else that could cause this that I might be missing?

**Update** The client had tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times with no change.  But I had him uninstall and reinstall and *override the default install location*.  This time it worked as expected.  It turns out that a previous version of the program *did* have "requireAdministrator" and it's like Windows is some how keeping track of that fact and is refusing to forget it, treating the new version the same even though it should run "asInvoker" now.

Comment: Is anything of interest logged in eventvwr's **Security** log?

Comment: No, nothing in event viewer security log.

Comment: http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/245-find-out-why-your-external-manifest-is-being-ignored claims the cache is tied to the modified date.